# How to send message after redirecting to another component in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-router

I have a user registration and on form submission, I am redirecting to another component (let's say Home page component), where I would like to display a Success message to the user.

I am able to redirect the user to Home page component on form submission and I have created message service to publish the messages and my home page component is subscribed to the messages.

**However, after redirecting the Home page component, the messages are not displayed.**

Here is the code:

```
  onSubmit(userForm){
     // save the record to db
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          let message = 'Thank you for signing up'; 
          this._messageService.sendMessage({text: message, category: 'success'});
          this._router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        error => {
          // error handling
        }
      )
  }
```

Here is the Messaging service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

export interface IMessage{
  text: string,
  category: string 
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MessageService {
  constructor() { }
  private subject = new Subject<any>();

    sendMessage(data: IMessage) {
        console.log("Sending message: ", data)
        this.subject.next({ data: data }); 
    }

    getMessage(): Observable<any> {
       return this.subject.asObservable();
    }

}
```

Home page subscribed to the messages

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService, IMessage } from '../message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  messages: IMessage[] = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { 
    // subscribe to messages
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(message => {
      if (message) {
        this.messages.push(message.data);
      } else {
        // clear messages when empty message received
        this.messages = [];
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: msg is not showing bcs that component is not initialized so you have to initialize that component first. what I suggest you is that write a common notification code in a component.ts bcs that component is already initialized

Comment: Refactor your code and move your service subscription to `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook, [**Reserve the constructor for simple initialization such as wiring constructor parameters to properties. The constructor shouldn't do anything. It certainly shouldn't call a function that makes HTTP requests to a remote server as a real data service would.**](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#call-it-in-ngoninit)

Comment: Thank, you. I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you subscribing on `Subject` object after it's already sent information about the message. `Subject` is not saving information about last data that was sent to it, it's just sending data to subscribed objects and that's it.

Instead of using `Subject` try to use `BehaviorSubject`, in this case after subscription on it it will send last data that you trying to send from `onSubmit` function.